# How do you actively look at a file in your system to check if additional lines have been added in Java?

Tags: java

So I'm new to Java and am attempting to make a system that reads a log file every 30 seconds to check for additional lines of code, but the system I've made so far just doesn't work at all...

(just a couple of other notes: the File "current" was instantiated elsewhere but has the same file path as the other files, the file paths are correct in my actual code, and finally my apologies for the unorthodoxly poor question structure, I'll add more to this post if need be) (also any suggestions on the structure of my actual code are welcome)

```
public static void main(String args[])throws FileNotFoundException {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\/*...*/latest.log");
            
            try {
                if(getLineCount(f)>getLineCount(current))
                    System.out.println("yes");
                else
                    System.out.println("no");
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            try {
                System.out.println(getLineCount(current)+" "+getLineCount(f));
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            current = new File("C:\\Users\\/*...*/latest.log");
            System.out.println();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 3000, 3000);
    System.out.println("hi!!!!");
}
private static int getLineCount(File f)throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    int count = 0;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        sc.nextLine();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more clarification on "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Is the output not what you expected?

Comment: Just use the [java.nio.file.WatchService Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to see if the file has been modified (edited or added to etc). [See here for a tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/listening-to-fileevents-with-java-nio). You can filter to watch a single specific file if you like. Also (if you like), you can run your code through any one of the WatchService events.